# Data Validation list with additional arbitrary values

Tags: excel

How can I setup Data Validation using a List whereby some options come from a dynamic named range and some are static?

For example;
I have a sheet of lookups with a 1-column table, Priority_tbl, whereby the DataBodyRange is named Priority_lst (Low, Moderate, High, Extreme). This is used in multiple other places in the file so don't want to change it for a single instance and ideally don't want to duplicate it without good reason.

I then have an Actions table (Actions_tbl) whereby I want to use validation to populate a Priority field. For the source, I start with `=Priority_lst` but then also want to include **Not assessed** and **Not required** as valid options.

Is this possible without needing to add another table/list that duplicates the current Priority_lst?

TIA, Josh

Comment: When assigning a validation list from a range, I believe it needs to be a single contiguous range

Comment: Thanks Tim. I feared that was the answer. I'd tried a few different things without any luck.

Comment: Define a range for the data validation, then have each of those cells pointing to a separate range and bring back the result wanted by vlookup etc